# Understanding objects in Java

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to understand about objects in Java and how they reside in memory. I'm experimenting with the following application:

```
private static final Unsafe U = getUnsafe();

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    offsets(Test.class);
}

private static <T> void offsets(Class<T> clazz){
    Arrays.stream(clazz.getFields())
       .forEach(f -> 
            System.out.println(f.getName() + " offset:" + U.objectFieldOffset(f)
       )
    );
}

public static class Test{
    public boolean b;
    public byte b1;
    public short b2;
    public int b3;
}
```

The output:

```
b offset:18
b1 offset:19
b2 offset:16
b3 offset:12
```

***QUESTION 1:*** I experimented with many kind of object and was surprised that fields offsets never less then 12. What is that 12? Some reserved object metadat?

***QUESTION 2:*** Moreover I thought that memory alignement of the data structure should be equal to 4 or 8 bytes. But why offset of b1 is 19, for instance? How to interpret this `Unsafe::fieldOffset` output?

*P.S. This is for educational purpose only, not intended for using in production.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Some reserved object metadata?" Yes.

"memory alignement of the data structure should be equal to 4 or 8 bytes." For the object as a whole, yes, but not necessarily for individual fields.

Comment: Is there a way to estimate the alignment of `Test` in that case?

Comment: Btw, very interesting... Why is the offset of `b` field 18? Even if it put as the first one?

Comment: Could you advise some tool for monitoring object layout (with all metadata)?